# WordPress high Steal time on Linux Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: ubuntu, swap, amazon-ec2, aws, wordpress

I have a dynamic Wordpress website with multiple plugins, installed over an AWS EC2 t2.micro Instance with a Linux Ubuntu 16.04.

At some point of working on the admin panel on different occasions, the website becomes extremely slow. I Installed netdata [here](http://cosyclassics.cz:50000/) for an easier way of monitoring the CPU performance. It seems that the steal time out is eating up the CPU even sometimes if I stopped working on the website completely. When I checked top command to track the processes, I found out that Kswapd0 is taking from 95% - 100% of the CPU whenever I am running on the website, Check here: [image: Performance Screenshot.]

When I searched the issue and followed the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259739/kswapd0-is-taking-a-lot-of-cpu) to make sure that the swap only starts being used when there is 0% left memory using the following command : `echo vm.swappiness=0 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.confnothing changed.`

I read that it might be because I am using a micro instance and multiple people are facing this issue as well, I do not mind increasing the instance if this is the issue and pay for a small or medium instance but I just need to make sure of that before launching the website.

Any help on this? I am new to this so please let me know if there is supposed to be any further information in order to be able to find a solution.

Comment: You don't have to guess.  Look at your CPU credit balance graph for the instance, in the console.  When you have no credits, or very few credits, this is the *expected, normal* behavior. Most likely, "multiple people are facing this issue" because they don't [read the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html).

Comment: Please don't post an image next time - text is much easier for people to search and doesn't need enlarging.